# App working properly on localhost but after deploy on heroku , it doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, heroku

I want to create a video chat app. But My app is working properly on localhost. But in heroku, When others participate joined. It doesn't show his video on my window. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for the server. Server.js -

```
    const express = require('express');
    
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server)
    const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')
    const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
    const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server,{
      debug: true
    })
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    
    app.use('/peerjs', peerServer)
    
    app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
      res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
    })
    
    
    app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
      res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
    })
    
    
    io.on('connection',socket =>{
      socket.on('join-room',(roomId, userId)=>{
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId);
      })
    })


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

It is the main script. Script.js-

```
const socket = io('/')

const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video_grid')

let myVideoStream;
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true;

var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: '/peerjs',
  host: '/',
  port: '3030'
}); 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {
  myVideoStream = stream;
  addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

  peer.on('call', call=>{
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream=>{
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      
    })
  })

  socket.on('user-connected', userId =>{
    connecToNewUSer(userId, stream);
    alert('Somebody connect', userId)
    
  })
  
}
)
  peer.on('open', id =>{
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id) ;
  })
   

  


  const connecToNewUSer = (userId, stream) => {
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream =>{
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      
    }) 
  }

  

  function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
      video.play()
    })
    videoGrid.append(video)
  }
```

It is the ejs file. room.ejs -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ZOOM</title>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video_grid">
      
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it say in the browser console?

Comment: Have you configured the procfile?

Comment: Browser console doesn't show anything. I configure Procfile also.